# Examine $L_1, L_2$ for differentiability

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, limits, functions, continuity

I need help

let $h: ℝ → ℝ$ be a limited function and let :

$L_1:ℝ → ℝ, x → xh (x)$

$L_2:ℝ → ℝ, x → x²h (x)$

The problems: examine $L_1$ and $L_2$ for differentiability and for continuity at the point $x_0 = 0$.

I don't know how to start  and what follows after the limitedness of $h$?

Comment: You should type using [Mathjax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) and see [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question)

Comment: What do you mean by "limited"?  Can you give a definition?